Show reference/foreign key data in DBVisualizer on adding a new row
In the DBVisualizer, is it possible to look into the ForeignKeys and preview them when adding new rows of data?
In HeidiSQL, when you double-click on the corresponding cell, a select statement is executed that displays the data from the reference table:

Unfortunately I can't find anything about this in the DBVisualizer settings:


DbVisualizer developer here!
This seems like a quite useful feature to have, but unfortunately, we don't currently support it.
However, I have taken the liberty of adding it to our internal list of feature requests, and I will bring it up for discussion with the rest of the team.
Cheers!
